# how i call other class java android

Tags: java, android

i try to call other class i try put i cant Is it impossible to do that ?
i try to call other class i try put i cant Is it impossible to do that ?

i try to call other class i try put i cant Is it impossible to do that ?

this my class 1

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

    private ImageView fashionImg;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_layout, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true); //

        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // get the button view
        fashionImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        // set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
        fashionImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        rydat.class);
                startActivity(Intent);
            }
        });

        fashionImg = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        // set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
        fashionImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        minb.class);
                startActivity(Intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

this class is working

rydat.class

```
package com.example.androidtabmenucustomizeactionbaritemclick;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;


public class rydat extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener {
    private static final String TAG = rydat.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "rayady.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newpdf);
        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(10)
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

put this not work

minb.class

pls Help me  to fix this  problem

```
package com.example.androidtabmenucustomizeactionbaritemclick;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class minb extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mmnn, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true); //

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why spam the same text three times? How does that help the question?

Comment: coz i add 1 time the stackoverflow say you must add more

Comment: That should have been your cue that adding more relevant was necessary, not the same uninformative message 3 times.

Comment: i cant can you help me with My case

Answer (score 0):

First, classes are named using Camel case and should be in a file with the same name with a .java extension.  So for your second class, the class should be named `Rydat`, and it should be in a file called `Rydat.java`

When you want to launch this activity, you would do so by calling:

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Rydat.class);
startActivity(Intent)
```

Similarly, if you have another activity (which you aren't showing code for) that you want to be called Minb, you would do something similar.

Also, you can't `startActivity` on a `Fragment` - so either Minb needs to be changed to an `Activity` or you need start an activity that adds the fragment.

Another problem in your code is that you re-using the `fashionImg` variable for two different ImageViews and setting the click listener twice.  That's not going to work.  You should create separate variables for each `ImageView`.

You need to know the basics of Java programming in order to use it for android development.

Edit: Updated to address Minb fragment.

Comment: it is work with me put this code not work iwant call this

Comment: You can't startActivity on a fragment - I updated the answer to reflect the code you added.